# Selenium Python as a Service Website

Tags: python, selenium, aem

I want to make a web app with a UI where users can enter a **file_name** and click a "download" button on this site that will execute a selenium-python script that goes to another website:

browser.get("http://mywebsite/crx/packmgr/index.jsp")

....clicks through page buttons, enters **file_name**, clicks "Download" on new site...

Then I want to download this file to the user's computer.

This script works on my local.

How can I get this on a website? Serving to multiple users at once?

Thank you!!

-Hal

Comment: You need to use flask for this. Please learn flask and implement a webserver to complement this. But do remember the file will be downloaded on your server and your chrome and wont use client's chrome